Does increasing one's probiotic uptake lower the chance of getting sick after swimming in waters of questionable quality?
I read on Olympic triathletes hope the Seine River is clean enough for swimming after recent rains regarding swimming in waters of questionable quality:

“We've all been upping our probiotic uptake, which I think is the best way to assure that we have a strong gut and we can withstand any sort of sickness that might come our way,” she said.

Does increasing one's probiotic uptake lower the chance of getting sick after swimming in waters of questionable quality?

Related: Probiotics and immune health – However, the results of clinical studies regarding probiotic application are preliminary and require further confirmation. But that was in 2011.

...OTOH in 2019 Probiotics are touted as good for the gut says probiotics might actually upset the balance of so-called “good” bacteria in the gut and interfere with the immune response.

My guess would be that  "it's not impossible/a crazy idea, the protective effect is probably weak, no-one really knows".

Good question Franck. On the same topic, one thing that can help is ear plugs.  They can especially help reduce the chance of localized infections.  Of course, they have to be the sealing type, and must be appropriately cleaned after each use.
